# How to replace last five occurrences of a string in a file via Linux command?

Tags: text-processing, command-line

I want to replace last 5 occurrences of a string in a file via linux command.

Please advise.

Examples:

Input is `ababa ababa ababa ababa ababa ababa`
Replace `aba` with `abX`
Expected output: `ababa abXba abXba abXba abXba abXba`

Input is `ababa ababa ababa ababa ababa ababa ababa`
Replace `aba` with `12`
Exected output `ababa ababa 12ba 12ba 12ba 12ba 12ba`

Note: The string can span several lines or be any where in the files. But wanted to replace only the last 5 matching occurrences

If 100 matches in a file, last 5 matches to be replaced.

Comment: Welcome to the site. When asking questions about text processing, please be sure to add a minimal reproducible example of the problem - i.e. (possible anonymized) example input, desired output, what you already tried, and in which way the output you got from your attempts deviates from the expectation. That way you can avoid receiving answers that you already know won't work, and contributors can verify proposed solutions before posting them as answers.

Comment: Note that linux is just a kernel. It doesn't have *commands*. Debian, Android,  ChromeOS are OSes that do use the Linux kernel and have *commands*, though different between each other.

Comment: Please note that the example mentioned by Stéphane was only to illustrate one of the ambiguities in the wording of your question. In order for contributors to help you, you will need to provide (ideally several) examples of the input that are as close as privacy allows to the real text you want to process (along with the desired output).

Answer (score 1):

With `perl`:

```
perl -0777 -pse '
  $count = () = /\Q$string\E/g;
  s{\Q$string\E}{$count-- > $n ? $& : $replacement}ge
  ' -- -string='whatever
even multiple
lines' -replacement='whatever as well' -n=5 -- file
```

Add the `-i` option to edit the `file` in-place as opposed to sending the result on stdout.

- `-p` is the `sed` mode where the code in the `e`xpression passed to `-e` is evaluated for ever record in the file.
- `-0777` sets the record separator to an impossible byte value, which means there is only one record: the full contents of the file.
- `-s` allows passing values of variables as `-varname=value` arguments.
- `/regexp/g`, short for `$_ =~ m{regexp}g`, the `regexp`, `m`atcher applied globally to the current record (in `$_`) returns true/false if the regexp matches in scalar context and the list of matches in list context. Here the regexp is `\Q$string\E`, the `\Q` and `\E` being to *quote* so `$string` is taken as a literal string even if it contains regexp operators.
- with `() = /regexp/g`, we force a list context, here by assigning to an empty list of variables, so essentially discarding them, but as the result is used in a scalar assignment, that gives you the number of elements, so the number of matches of the regexps, so the number of occurrences of `$string` in the record (the whole contents of the `file`).
- `s{regexp}{replacement}ge`: `s`ubstitutes `g`lobally `regexp` matches with the `replacement`. With `e`, the `replacement` is interpreted as a perl code expression.
- `condition ? iftrue : iffalse` is the usual ternary operator from C found in most languages.
- `$count--` returns `$count` before increment. If `< $n` we replace with `$&` which contains what was matched, so does nothing and if not with `$replacement`.

Comment: I've often wondered if serial port line noise would ever compile to a valid perl script. And I have read the perl haiku scripts for inspiration.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one method using awk and sed.
Count the number of occurrences of the string in the file by:

```
grep -o mystring file1.txt | wc -l
```

Let's suppose this number is 20. Now replace the first 20-5=15 occurrences by some arbitrary string, say PWWP

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if(c<15&&$i=="mystring"){c++;sub("mystring","PWWP",$i)}}}1' file1.txt > file2.txt
```

Delete all remaining occurrences (5 of them) from file2.txt using sed:

```
sed -i 's/mystring//g' file2.txt
```

and restore your original file by a second sed operation:

```
sed -i 's/PWWP/mystring/g' file2.txt
mv file2.txt file1.txt
```